# Issues while building the custom recipe with yocto

Tags: c, yocto, file-handling

Hello guys I am trying to create an application for my image using yocto, I am using meson compiler as it handles cross compiling.My application compiles as expected on my linux host .The application reads the input data from the files (.bin files) for compilation.

When i try to bitbake the recipe get the error, I tried to change the recipes but no use, can someone please where am i going wrong.

/*******************************************************************************/

```
Initialising tasks: 100%     |##########################################################################################  ################################################################################| Time:   0:00:00
Sstate summary: Wanted 7 Local 0 Mirrors 0 Missed 7 Current 220 (0% match, 96%  complete)
NOTE: Executing Tasks 

ERROR: appxyz-0-0 do_package: QA Issue: appxyz: Files/directories were installed but not shipped in any package:
  /usr/lib
Please set FILES such that these items are packaged. Alternatively if they are unneeded, avoid installing them or delete them within do_install.
appxyz: 1 installed and not shipped files. [installed-vs-shipped]

ERROR: appxyz-0-0 do_package: Fatal QA errors were found, failing task.

ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/yocto/build/tmp-glibc/work/riscv64-oe-  linux/appxyz/0-0/temp/log.do_package.60686
ERROR: Task (/home/yocto/meta-application/recipes-app_xyz/appxyz/appxyz_0_0.bb:do_package) failed with exit code '1'

NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 973 tasks of which 961 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.
NOTE: Writing buildhistory
NOTE: Writing buildhistory took: 1 seconds
NOTE: Build completion summary:

NOTE:   do_populate_sysroot: 0.0% sstate reuse(0 setscene, 1 scratch)
NOTE:   do_deploy_source_date_epoch: 0.0% sstate reuse(0 setscene, 1 scratch)

NOTE:   do_package: 0.0% sstate reuse(0 setscene, 1 scratch)
NOTE:   do_populate_lic: 0.0% sstate reuse(0 setscene, 1 scratch)

Summary: 1 task failed:
  /home/yocto/meta-application/recipes-application/appxyz/appxyz_0_0.bb:do_package
Summary: There were 2 ERROR messages shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

/***********************************************************/

This is my recipe file

```
inherit autotools pkgconfig
inherit meson
PRIORITY = "optional"
SECTION  = "examples"
LICENSE  = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"
SRC_URI = "file://appxyz/"




S = "${WORKDIR}"
B = "${WORKDIR}/build_dir"
MESON_SOURCEPATH = "${S}/appxyz"




do_install() {

     install -d ${D}${bindir}
     install -d ${D}${libdir}

     install -m 0755 ${B}/appxyz ${D}${bindir}
     

}


FILES_${PN} +=  "${bindir}/ ${bindir}/appxyz"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is complaining about `[installed-vs-shipped]` issue, so I assume the solution would be the following:

You are creating `${D}${libdir}` but not present in `FILES_${PN}`.

Try removing it from `do_install` or add `${libdir}` to `FILES_${PN}`.

Comment: Hello @Talel BELHADJSALEM, 
Thnak you for the comment, I removed install -d ${D}${libdir} from do_install and now it builds, can you tell me how can i use other method as I did not get it. 
Also can yocto take a runtime File handling , as in my my application reads from a file?

Comment: First, if my response answers your question, kindly accept it as correct answer. Now, I did not get what you mean by the last part (File handling) ?

Comment: I mean my c application it uses fopen() and close to read data from the files, How can i handle this task in yocto? basically  yocto manges this based on the code generates the executable.
But if i want to read and write files fom my microcomtroller how would I tell yocto to do that?

Comment: This is a completely other topic, I still did not get your point, I need more information and details to answer you the proper way, you can open another question with the details.

Comment: @redythy When this package is installed on the system, should it create the folder /usr/lib? If yes, add it to FILES_${PN}. If no, remove it from the install script.

Comment: @redythy Yocto has nothing to do with your program reading or writing files. Yocto basically installs the program...